# Polymer.js without material design?

Tags: polymer, material-design

I like the idea of reusable web elements in Polymer.js. However I am not convinced that Google's material design is the way to go, especially in desktop environment.

So is there a way of "styling" Polymer or will there be any other "skins" than just material design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer is **not** equal to material design. It's only a library that makes developing web components a lot easier. It won't stop you from creating new components that follow other design guidelines (although currently the `paper-elements` make most of the UI web components provided by Polymer).

And as for styling, Polymer promotes the up-and-coming **CSS Custom Properties** (variables and mixins) for theming web components.

Comment: OK, but currently there are no other "themes" or "skins" implemented in polymer besides material design, right ?

Comment: Polymer is a library for creating web components, and the paper elements are components made with Polymer.  They are fairly separate projects, and you can make elements in whatever style you prefer, because you're ultimately still designing with the same HTML/CSS/JS.